# Can not parse the Elem from XML in Scala

Tags: xml, scala

This is what the code looks like

```
import scala.xml.{Elem, Node, PCData}
import scala.xml.transform.{RewriteRule, RuleTransformer}

val doc: Elem = <data>
    <level1>
      <Weekly>
        <Properties>
          <Property key="Sun"/>
          <Property key="Mon"/>
          <Property key="Tue"/>
        </Properties>
      </Weekly>
    </level1>
    <level2>
      <Monthly>
        <Properties>
          <Property key="Jan"/>
          <Property key="Feb"/>
          <Property key="Mar"/>
        </Properties>
      </Monthly>
    </level2>
  </data>

final class traverseRule extends RewriteRule {
  override def transform(ns: Seq[Node]): Seq[Node] = ns match {
    case n: Node => println(n.label)
      n

  }
}
new RuleTransformer(new traverseRule()).transform(doc).head
```

What I get back is

```
#PCDATA
#PCDATA
#PCDATA
#PCDATA
Property
#PCDATA
Property
#PCDATA
Property
#PCDATA
Properties
#PCDATA
Weekly
#PCDATA
level1
#PCDATA
#PCDATA
#PCDATA
#PCDATA
Property
#PCDATA
Property
#PCDATA
Property
#PCDATA
Properties
#PCDATA
Monthly
#PCDATA
level2
#PCDATA
data
```

**Needed?**
I need the elements `data`, `level`, `Weekly` instead of `#PCDATA`. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to list all the elements in the XML document the following function would work.

```
import scala.xml.{Elem, Node, PCData}

val doc: Elem = <data>
    <level1>
      <Weekly>
        <Properties>
          <Property key="Sun"/>
          <Property key="Mon"/>
          <Property key="Tue"/>
        </Properties>
      </Weekly>
    </level1>
    <level2>
      <Monthly>
        <Properties>
          <Property key="Jan"/>
          <Property key="Feb"/>
          <Property key="Mar"/>
        </Properties>
      </Monthly>
    </level2>
  </data>


def listNodes(elem: scala.xml.Elem): Seq[scala.xml.Elem] = {
    elem.child flatMap {
        case x: scala.xml.Elem => x +: listNodes(x) 
        case _ => Nil
    }
}

val elements = doc +: listNodes(doc)

scala> elements.map(_.label)
res0: Seq[String] = ArrayBuffer(data, level1, Weekly, Properties, Property, Property, Property, level2, Monthly, Properties, Property, Property, Property)
```

The elements is sequence of Scala elements that has all the element tags in the document. The function `listNodes` function recursively find all element nodes in the XML node.